# Error fetching SQL Server 2008 database with JBOSS Tools 3.3 and JBOSS 7.1

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jboss, jboss-tools

While trying to create a Hibernate Configuration using JBOSS Tools (to access a database schema in SQLServer 2008) I get an error.

After creating the Hibernate Mapping file (an empty one) and the Hibernate Configuration File, and the Console Configuration, I try to open the Database in the the Hibernate configuration, I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Getting database metadata
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getMetaData(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:63)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.caseForSearch(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:22)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:476)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:126)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host XX.XX.XX.XX, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.libs.FakeDelegatingDriver.connect(FakeDelegatingDriver.java:42)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getConnection(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:121)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getMetaData(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:60)
... 12 more
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://XX.XX.XX.XX:1433;DatabaseName=TESTDEV</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">TEST</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">TESTDEV</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
</session-factory>
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a problem of JBoss Tools?

EDIT:
While creating a console configuration, if I choose the "database connection" and edit it,it also fails to test the connection, getting the same error as before:

```
Ping failed: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.16.14.36, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I can access the database with the same properties using SQuirreL, or by pinging in an Eclipse that doesn't have JBoss Tools installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with the proxy definition :)